# Images can not be changed

Tags: nodes, media, files

This seems strange to me, but everything worked fine before i made my site live. I set up all the content and made a backup. Uploaded everything to its server but now i can't change my images. When i remove the current image this comes up (see image) instead of being able to upload a new image
[image]

And console throws this error:
[image]

I have tried all the versions of jquery and my jquery_update in contrib is 7.x-2.7

Could it be something with the permissions? i have site/default/files-775

Comment: are you using ubuntu?

Comment: @NoSssweat, Not using ubuntu

Comment: I had a similar issue. I solved it by removing all PHP extensions not enabled on my dev setup from the hosting PHP configuration. I remember googling it and finding a post on this that mentioned the exact PHP extension, but can't remember which one. And is your PHP configured to upload files larger than 2MB? My error was thrown on uploading images via Media Ajax. Also error 500.

Comment: @J.Reynolds 

none of that worked

Comment: it might be a permissions issue. Your sites folder needs to have read and write permission.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed any module that alters with the drupal paths or jquery_update module version can cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that before making the site live `cache` was disabled in development server.If not try disabling `cache` in live site.